# Unable to update Multiple cloums in a sql database table using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi, pyodbc

I'm currently working on a school project. I need to update GPS coordinates in table. I'm using Raspberry pi board, pyodbc, freeTds and sql database. I cant update multiple items in a row..

```
cursor.execute("update Gps_table set longitude=(?) latitude=(?) where gps_id=1", s1, s2)
```

This above code doesn't work.. but i had figure it out, when i pass only one variable at a time it works. Which means those below codes are working..

```
cursor.execute("update Gps_table set longitude=(?) where gps_id=1", s1)
cursor.execute("update Gps_table set latitude=(?) where gps_id=1", s2)
```

But i need to update those two parameters at once. Can any one help me out Please. Thanks for reading this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [SQL UPDATE syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#BasicSyntax):

```
cursor.execute("update Gps_table set longitude=?,latitude=? where gps_id=1", s1, s2)
```